# MVC - reference a model from another model

Tags: model-view-controller, design-patterns

I've this scenario in my application:

- Controller1

  - .GetItems()
- Model1

  - .GetItems()
- Controller2

  - .GetCurrentUser()
- Model2

  - .CurrentUser

In this scenario Controller1.GetItems() calls Model1.GetItems() method. Model1.GetItems() method needs to know (for example) what is the role of the current user to build the correct list of items, and it should get it from the Model2.CurrentUser property (that stores the cached information about the current user).

Is it a good practice to acces a model from another model?

Thanks,
Regards

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are going to run into some arguments about the best way to do this, but at the end of the day, you have two options. Either you can have the model pull the information it needs from the other model or you can have the controller pass the information needed.

Based upon what I have read, as long as the model does not have any controller logic or view logic you are good so there is nothing wrong with having the model know about other models. However, others have argued that having the controller pass the information that is needed makes the code a bit easier to document since you can see that the model requires information from somewhere else. At the end of the day though, I see both as being valid and which one you choose to use will likely come down to personal preference.

---

**Design - Controller Provides Data**

> ModelOne
>
> - User GetCurrentUser()
>
> ModelTwo
>
> - Items[] GetItems(User)

**Snippet - Controller Proivdes Data**

```
Controller {
  function doWork() {
    User user = ModelOne.GetCurrentUser();
    Items[] items = ModelTwo.GetItems(user);
  }
}
```

---

**Design - Model Gets Data**

> ModelOne
>
> - User GetCurrentUser()
>
> ModelTwo
>
> - Items[] GetItems()

**Snippet - Model Gets Data**

```
ModelTwo {
  Items[] GetItems() {
    User user = ModelOne.GetCurrentUser();

    ...

  }
}

Controller {
  function doWork() {
    Items[] items = ModelTwo.GetItems();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. So I prefer that the model gets data from the other model. The reason is: posting the question on stackoverflow I simplified the scenario. In the real scenario the model could need also other information from other models (for example another model that owns information about the current's user loyalty level) in an extensible way. So I prefer to centralize the logic in the Model1.GetItems() that will use all models it needs to generate the correct items list.

Answer (score 3):

If your second model is going to referenced often by your first, you could compile your model classes into a separate library?

Comment: model classes are already compiled into a separate assembly. What is the problem about this? I don't understand.

Answer (score 2):

I think you shouldn't have references between models, the right way is to use the controller for this link. So in your case you could pass the CurrentUser as a parameter in the GetItems method.

Comment: So, you say that I should reference the two models inside Controller1 and then inside Controller1.GetItems() I should: 1) call Model2.GetCurrentUser() and get the user; 2) call Model1.GetItems(user) passing it the user. Right?

Comment: Yes, if these 2 models are going to be used in the same flow I think it would make sense to do it in one controller. Or if you need controllers coupled to models as part of your abstraction pattern, you could use a third controller which has references to both controllers and do the same.